# Node js Cron Job execution after 14 days

Tags: node.js, node-cron

```
cron.schedule(5 4 */14 * *){}
```

Is there any way to make it so it executes continously after 14 days without a reset?
[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with `Later.js` module [which supports DayOfTheYear](https://breejs.github.io/later/time-periods.html#day-of-year) out of the box.

Comment: does my answer solves your problem? Could you accept it and mark question as solved? Or you found another solution?

Comment: It helped a lot, sorry I forgot to mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your certain case, the problem is in using [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) and the schedule module itself.

```
*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of the week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Since the fourth asterisk represents the day of the month (and the sixth is day or week) you can't avoid the reset.

But you can always find a scheduling module with a **day of the year** support.

[Later.js](https://breejs.github.io/later/) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@breejs/later)) as a part of Bree module could help you with that, I guess.

Or can write your own wrapper function manually via [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) or [day.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)